# Recompile FMX.Consts Delphi XE5

Tags: delphi, constants, firemonkey

How to recompile FMX.Consts in RAD Studio XE5 Delphi?

On Android the MessageDlg function and the buttons appear with the title in English. I need translate to portuguese.
This step solves my problem?

Comment: Aren't these constants resource strings?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan They're hardcoded unit scope variables in FMX.Dialogs in `ButtonNames: array[TMsgDlgBtn] of string = ('Yes', 'No', 'OK'... etc`.  It's probably a better idea to build a custom dialog, in any case, rather than modify the framework.  Modifying the framework is never a good solution.